# Does the NSString returned from NSArray objectAtIndex as autorelease or retain

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, retain, autorelease

I have a string returned back from an array, just wonder if I need to release it after using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects returned from `-objectAtIndex:` are technically both.

The code looks something like this:

```
 -(id) objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index
 { 
      return [[objects_[index] retain] autorelease];
 }
```

So they don't belong to you, but if you remove it from the array, it won't be immediately deallocated.

Comment: But it isn't true, as objectAtIndex: doesn't retain+autorelease it. You can easily check it with this code: https://gist.github.com/mkramskoy/f94755191b758fe430b3a777ea07932d

Comment: @wirrwarr This answer was before ARC existed. The mechanics of containers (and return values in ObjC in general) changed at the time ARC was released, due to the addition/existence of [objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/).

Comment: Hm, but i tested it with manual memory management, as you can see from my gist. I don't think that MMM behaviour could change when ARC was introduced because of back compatibility, or I'm missing something here?

Comment: @wirrwarr Manual memory management under recent versions of clang still emits arc-aware instructions (not calls to objc_msgSend, but to objc_retain, objc_release, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this blog post, which does a great job summarizing the rules for Objective C memory management: http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/.

In particular, rule #1 applies here - you only need to release an object if you own it and you own it if you alloc, copy or new it (or if you explicitly retained it). You didn't do any of those things, so you don't need to release it.

Whether it's autoreleased or not depends on how the string was originally created but you don't need to worry about that since you are not responsible for releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

autoreleased.

That is with (almost?) any object returned by a method, it would make memory management overly complicated if it wasn't. It is why we all love autorelease.

Comment: Couple of exceptions: `+new`, `+alloc`, and `-init` off the top of my head don't follow those rules.

Comment: Yes, but I did not want to cause any confusion that you don't need to release objects created by `+new`, `+alloc`, and `+init`

Comment: It is not necessarily autoreleased; it is simply unowned by the caller.